# Trouble using FindInstance with MatrixRank

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm really confused about what's going wrong with my call to [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html):

```
FindInstance[MatrixRank[{{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {(-1)^i1, 1, 0}}] == 3,{i1}, Integers]
```

> {{i1 -> 33}}

The matrix `{{0,1,1},{1,0,1},{-1,1,0}}` has rank 2.  Also when I repeat the above call with the `MatrixRank` function set equal to 2, `FindInstance` returns `{}`.  What am I missing??

Comment: Try `MatrixRank[{{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {(-1)^h, 1, 0}}]` or `MatrixRank[{{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {h, h, h}}]`

Comment: Using the variable "h" instead of "i1" gave the same result.  Replacing the last row with {h,h,h} also returned {h->33}, which in this case is true.

Comment: No :) , I mean "look at the calc result". The problem is not with FindInstance[], but previous.

Comment: Ah! The Matrix Rank is always evaluating to three and not factoring in the variable h.  It makes sense why the code is not working properly now.  Do you know why MatrixRank behaves this way or what I can do to fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: MatrixRank is not working as you expect for free symbols Try **
Clear[k];
MatrixRank[{{1, 1}, {1, k}}]
k = 1;
MatrixRank[{{1, 1}, {1, k}}]**

Comment: @belisarius I figured out I can fix it by calling to Det instead of MatrixRank.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Better to use a black box function that only evaluates for explicit integer values.

In[13]:= mrank[n_Integer] := MatrixRank[{{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {(-1)^n, 1, 0}}]
nval = n /. First[FindInstance[mrank[n] == 3, n, Integers]]

Out[14]= 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with MatrixRank used in this way is explained in the Help:

[image]